# PHP angled single quote vs stright single quote

Tags: php

I had a developer create some code for me and he has used angled single quotes throughout the SQL statements. I have never used these before and was hoping someone could explain the difference between angled and straight?

If I replace all angled with straight quotes the queries dont work.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html for identifier quoting rules. Database, table & column identifier names in MySQL are quoted with backquotes, while string literals are quoted with single quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angled quotes (`` ` ``, actually called backticks) are used to delimit identifiers, e.g. fields and table names. Straight quotes are used to delimit strings, e.g. `'Hello, world!'`. You can't mix the two.